# How to fire `onMouseEnter` while mouse-button is pressed?

Tags: javascript

How can I make JavaScript fire the `onMouseEnter`-event of a target `<div>`-element while another dragged `<div>` enters the element (with a pressed mouse-button)?

For several reasons I cant use the `onDrag...` events...

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5dgnez9e/3/

Comment: It is working fine on my Chrome 46. Maybe, can you provide us with your code?

Comment: Thanks, I provided a fiddle.

Comment: So, it works with pure mouse, but not with an element being drag.

Comment: yepp. Seems to be an issue for quite some time. I hope someone found a solution for this by now?

Answer (score 1):

You should listen on document for `mousedown` and `mouseup` and store the mouse state on a global variable, than you can check on `mouseenter` event of the element for the state

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mouseClicked = false;
    document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
      mouseClicked = true;
    }

    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
      mouseClicked = false
    }

    $(".element").on("mouseenter",function(){
        if(mouseClicked){
            console.log("entered");
        }
    });
});
```

You can check a working example on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbeskzf1/1/)

Comment: Problem is that the `mouseEnter` isnt fired at all while dragging an element over it

Comment: That's why you need to use onmousedown and onmouseup instead of draggable.

Comment: if `mouseEnter` isnt fired this does not work: I wont reach the check for `mouseClicked`...

Answer (score -1):

I made a small snippett, check it out :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:160px;height:160px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).svg/2000px-Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).svg.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="120" height="120">

</body>
</html>
```

---

Mouse drag should work.

Anyways a workaound :

Is to maintain a boolean which keeps track of the mouse press event.

when pressed set the boolean flag to true.

when released set the boolean flag to false.

When the mouse enter even is trigerred, check for the flag.